# Turn javascript webdriver.Capabilities into string

Tags: javascript, selenium, typescript, protractor

Using protractor (selenium) in typescript I can call `browser.driver.getCapabilities()` to get an object that looks something like this:

```
Capabilities {
  'acceptSslCerts' => true,
  'applicationCacheEnabled' => false,
  'browserConnectionEnabled' => false,
  'browserName' => 'chrome',
  'chrome' => { chromedriverVersion: '2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf)',
  userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir12788_29679' },
  'cssSelectorsEnabled' => true,
  'databaseEnabled' => false,
  'handlesAlerts' => true,
  'hasTouchScreen' => false,
  'javascriptEnabled' => true,
  'locationContextEnabled' => true,
  'mobileEmulationEnabled' => false,
  'nativeEvents' => true,
  'networkConnectionEnabled' => false,
  'pageLoadStrategy' => 'normal',
  'platform' => 'Windows NT',
  'rotatable' => false,
  'takesHeapSnapshot' => true,
  'takesScreenshot' => true,
  'version' => '54.0.2840.71',
  'webStorageEnabled' => true }
```

That what it looks like when feed through console.log. **But how can I get this string representation in my code?**

`caps.toJSON()` returns nothing. `JSON.stringify(caps)`, also nothing. `for(let foo in caps)` doesn't yield anything either. the object looks like some kind of map. I want to save this object to a file, what special magic does console.log do and how can I do it?

If someone knows what kind of object this is that also would be helpful. I thought it might be an ES6 map, but unlike the example in [Converting ES6 Maps to and from JSON](http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html), it's not an iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `getCapabilities` returns an ES6 `MAP` object. It doesn't seem possible to directly serialize this object. So your best chance is probably to serialize the entries:

```
browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(caps => {
  var entries = Array.from(caps.entries());
  console.log(JSON.stringify(entries));
});
```

Or to convert the entries to an `Object` and then to serialize it:

```
browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(caps => {
  var obj = Array.from(caps.entries()).reduce((o, v) => (o[v[0]] = v[1], o), {});
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, there doesn't seem to be an `entries()` on this object?

Comment: It works as expected with my config (protractor@4.0.9). This is pure JS, so it could be an issue with the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Thanks, yes, sorry, I did check whether it was a typings issue and it is. Without bothering to extend the definitions, this works `(<any>caps).entries())`.